# Is there a way to animate clothes without cloth modifiers?

Tags: animation, modifiers, cloth-simulation

I tried making clothes for a character I want to animate by using cloth simulation, but that wasn't working for me. I could not get it right. So I ended up just modeling the clothes by duplicating selected faces from the character, separating them, scaling them up, and adjusting them so they'd fit the character. Is there any sort of modifier I can add to the clothes besides the cloth modifier that can make them behave like clothes and not pass through other objects? Would something like softbody work?[image]

Comment: "Is there any sort of modifier I can add to the clothes besides the cloth modifier that can make them behave like clothes and not pass through other objects?"  Quickest, easiest way to handle clothes in Blender, with a full-body mesh, is a surface deform modifier targeting that body mesh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking through YouTube for a bit, I found this tutorial and it seems like the perfect solution for my current situation.

https://youtu.be/XKBONVoHSdA